# Postmessage in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I send data using Postmessage, but to get them right is not obtained.

My attempts:

Variant 1:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
}, false);
```

Variant 2:

```
$.bind("message", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}, false);
```

First variant works, but is not used jQuery.  Show you how to use jQuery in this situation?

if needed sending code::

```
$(function() {
    var iframe = $('iframe#someFrame');
    setTimeout(function() {
    iframe[0].contentWindow.postMessage('message to localhost', '*');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: `$(window).on("message", function(event) { ... });` perhaps.. *Note: Not tested*

Comment: Why would you want to use jQuery in this situation? Not that I'm saying you shouldn't, it's your code, just out of interest

Comment: if i use that, `event.data` = undefined

Comment: @Blade0rz, because the boss said that my solution will not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the `originalEvent` from jQuery:

```
$(window).on("message", function(e) {
    var data = e.originalEvent.data;
});
```